# d3 won't update after adding data to child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

Here is how my data is supposed to look:

```
[{a:b, b:c, child:[k:d, m:w] }, {a:b, b:c, child:[k:d, m:w] }]
```

Dynamic data. I can push new data which will show up in dom. When I try to add more data to child,
I can see data in console, but it does not update element.

```
let main = svgContainer.selectAll("g").data(Data, function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });
      main.exit().remove();
      let group = main
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "g_groupMain")
        .attr("width", (d) => d.g_width)
        .attr("height", (d) => d.g_height)
        .attr("id", (d) => "g_" + d.id);

      group  ----> add data to child. Does not update. Many tries and methods.
        .selectAll("path")
        .data((d) => d.path_data)
        .join((enter) => {
          enter
            .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .classed("pathd", true)
            .attr("stroke-width", 5)
            .attr("id", (d) => "path_" + d.id)
            .attr("stroke", (d) => d.color)
            .attr("d", function(d) {
              return d.path;
            });
        });

      group
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "rect")
        .attr("id", (d) => "bound_" + d.id)
        .attr("fill", (d) => d.b_color)
        .attr("fill-opacity", "0.4")
        .attr("x", (d) => d.b_x)
        .attr("y", (d) => d.b_y)
        .attr("width", (d) => d.b_width)
        .attr("height", (d) => d.b_height)
        .attr("value", (d) => d.id);

      main.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d, i) {
        return d.path;
      });
      main
        .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("width", (d) => d.b_width + 20)
        .attr("height", (d) => d.b_height + 20)
        .attr("value", (d) => d.id)
        .attr("x", (d) => d.b_x - 10)
        .attr("y", (d) => d.b_y - 10);
```